# A few domain PC's with no connectivity to internet & some servers, but connectivity to DCs & devices on same VLAN

Tags: networking, dns, firewall, domain, vlan

We've recently been presented with a few PC's over the past week that all have the same symptoms, two of which are Dell Optiplex 5060's connected via ethernet back to some managed Cisco Catalyst switches, one of which is a Surface Pro 9 connected to a wifi access point which also leads back to said switches (firewall manages those AP's to some extent).

Ethernet PC's are on 192.168.3.0
Wifi devices are on 192.168.4.0
Servers are on 192.168.2.0 (more on that in a second)

The same symptoms plague each device:

- can NOT access the internet (trying to tracert to msn.com hits the default gateway (i.e. 192.168.3.1 but then fails to hop to the firewall)
- can NOT ping *non domain controller servers* on 192.168.2.0 vlan
- can ping domain controllers on 192.168.2.0 vlan
- can ping other PC's on same vlan
- DNS & DHCP seems fine, proper IP's are given to the devices, DNS records are updated and match/replicate across all 3 domain controllers
- no IP or other conflicts present in event viewer (nothing damning really present there). Even during troubleshooting if a PC receives a different IP the problem persists

It's seeming like a switching/VLAN issue, but that wouldn't explain why it's only a few and not the *dozens* of other devices that share the same switches and/or vlans? Also, if these end user devices (on 192.168.3.0 & 192.168.4.0) couldn't interact with *anything* from the server vlan (192.168.2.0) that would make sense and steer me toward a private vlan/promiscuity issue, but they're communicating with domain controllers over there just fine?

Comment: Since, as you state, the issue seems to be at the *switch*, look to how these device enroll in the LAN. Have you tried removing one and enrolling anew?